# ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')] Django Rest Framework Code require error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**When I'm save to data below mention error getting.**
{'grp_name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}

**Modely.py file**

```
# Create your models here.
class GroupMaster(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ("a","Active"),
        ("d","Deactive"),
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, default=None, null=True, blank= True)
    grp_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_type , default='a')
    create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.grp_name)
```

**Serializers.py file**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from base.models import GroupMaster


class GroupMasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupMaster
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
                        'code': {'required': False}, 
                        'create_by': {'required': False},
                        'create_at': {'required': False},
                        'update_at': {'required': False},
                        }
```

**View.py File**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from base.models import GroupMaster
from .serializers import GroupMasterSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def Add_Grp(request):
    serializer = GroupMasterSerializer(data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        print(str(serializer.errors))
    return Response("asdf")
```

**form.html file**

```
var grp_add_form = document.getElementById('grp_add_form')
  grp_add_form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/grp/add/'
    var id_grp_name = document.getElementById('id_grp_name').value
    console.log(id_grp_name)
    var id_status = document.getElementById('id_status').value
    var id_code = "d"
    fetch(url,{
          method:'POST',
          headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
              'id_code':id_code,
              'id_grp_name':id_grp_name,
              'id_status':id_status,
            })
          }
      ).then(function(response) {
        console.log('test')
      })
  });   
</script>
```

**I have already code field define null=true and blank=true now I don't know why this error getting and also commit not working for request.user save**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `GroupMaster` model is expecting a `grp_name` field and you ain't sent it in the request.
Could you also share the GroupMaster model?

---- Updated Answer

Your error message

```py
{'grp_name': [ErrorDetail(
        string='This field is required.', 
        code='required'
        )]
 }
```

means that you are forgetting to pass the `grp_name` field to the request, and because of that the model serializer `GroupMasterSerializer` pops up this error message when validating the serializer required fields, on `serializer.is_valid()`.

If not customized, the Django Rest Framework ModelSerializers fields are serialized/deserialized based only on the Django Models fields definitions.

And by default, the Django Models fields definitions come with `blank=False` and `null=False`, and this means that the field is required by the model.

In your model `GroupMaster`, the `grp_name` is defined as
`grp_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)`, so, it's `blank=False` and `null=False`, in a way that you always need to pass a value to it.

I did this test on the terminal and it worked well:

```py
 s = GroupMasterSerializer(
    data={
        'id_code': 'id_code',
        'id_status': 'id_status',
        'id_grp_name': 'id_grp_name',
        'grp_name': 'grp_name'
    }
)
```

```py
s.is_valid()
```

True

```py
s.errors
```

{}

Comment: I have check with print on django terminal and also check with console.log both print show grp_name  value

Comment: Hey, try it again passing the `grp_name` field for your serializer before saving it.